# Convert decimal to four hex digits

Tags: perl

Is there a way to convert decimal numbers to four hex digits? For example:

```
Decimal: 17    =>   Hex: 0x0011 
Decimal: 291   =>   Hex: 0x0123
Decimal: 4951  =>   Hex: 0x1357
```

Basically, I want to preserve the leading zeroes.

So far I have:

```
my $HEX_NUM = sprintf("%x", $DEC_NUM);
```

Is there a way to get the leading zeros without hardcoding them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a 0 [flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html#flags) and a [width](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html#(minimum)-width) in your printf specifier:

```
sprintf('%04x', $DEC_NUM);
```

Though from your example, you may also want the '#' flag (but you'd have to increase the width to 6 to accommodate the 0x).

Comment: Thanks for the links! If I want to do it for eight digits instead, but I want a space in between the first four and second four, is there a way to do that?

Comment: you could do `sprintf('%04x %04x', $num/0x10000, $num%0x10000)` (at least as long as $num is never negative).

Comment: fixed link: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-output-my-numbers-with-commas-added%3F